# How do I get rid of the mackeeper popup from http://mackeeperapp2.mackeeper.com?

Tags: macos

This is not the zeobit version. Adware scanner doesn't find anything. It pops up (or under) whenever I close Safari.

I have Mac OS X 10.7.5.

It is advertising MacKeeper and I would like it to bug off.

Comment: did you try to run the scan with http://www.clamxav.com/

Comment: MacKeeper ads pop up everywhere, whether you have any infection or not - after a while you become inured to them & learn to ignore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to /etc/hosts and mackeeper goes away forever:

```
127.0.0.1   mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1   www.mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1   mackeeperapp.zeobit.com
127.0.0.1   mackeeperapp.mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1   mackeeperapp2.mackeeper.com
```

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you the truth: MacKeeper is still there. Its connections to its home are just looping stupidly locally (127.0.0.1).

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. /etc/hosts prevents websites from loading. If you installed mackeeper's trojan that's a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was also sick of mackeeper but it was not uninstalling itself from my mac. I saw a review recommending Adwaremedic software.

http://www.adwaremedic.com/index.php

I downloaded it and all the mess is gone from my mac. Clean, no pop ups, no mackeeper, the stupid is gone from my computer.

It is free, no registration, and donation supported.

Comment: I don't use the tool, but the website looks legit and the manual removal instructions are quite nice if you've been burned by "fix" software before.

Comment: adwaremedic is a clean web server: 0 spyware, 0 cookies. This is so rare on the web:).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on computers, but I was having the exact same problem.  Went around all the forums trying to find a way to fix it and nothing worked. Then I realized that my firewall was turned off.  Once I fixed that *poof!* no more problems.

Comment: Beware, your firewall is blocking the MacKeeper calls home. The worm is still alive inside the apple :).